# What are the best practices to convert from double to float in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile

I try to display some double values on the microcharts but I receive error:

```
CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from "double" to "float"
```

Code:

```
List<EntryMicrocharts> entries = new List<EntryMicrocharts>
    {
        new EntryMicrocharts (weatherBindingData.WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].MainForecasts.TempForecast)
        {
            Color=SKColor.Parse("#ffa200"),
            Label = Info1Forecast,
            ValueLabel = "200",
            ValueLabelColor = SKColor.Parse("#ffa200")
        },
```

How can convert `weatherBindingData.WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].MainForecasts.TempForecast`
to float ?

Comment: [Convert.ToSingle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tosingle) or just cast `(float)...`

Comment: (float) not work.

Comment: "not work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Does it give you an error or exception, or crash, or what?

Comment: The same error when I put (float) before weatherBindingData.WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].MainForecasts.TempForecast

Comment: what is the actual type of TempForecast and what is the actual signature of the EntryMicrocharts constructor?

Comment: EntryMicrocharts accepted float but TempForecast is double

Comment: try the cast on a separate line before the constructor, or try Convert.ToSingle as @KlausGütter suggested